# Algorithms and generalisation of functions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

I admit I'm little bit poor in functions in mathematics.
But I'm in real urge to get this riddle out.
how to express `x(n)=x(n-1)+x(n-2)+1` where `n>1` and `x(0)=0` and `x(1)=1`.
in terms of function `y(n)=y(n-1)+n` where `n>1` and `y(0)=0` and `y(1)=1`.
I found the answer as `x(n)=y(n+2)-1` in a some pdf about AVL trees for the minimal number of nodes nmin(n) of an AVL tree of height n.

Please explain.

Comment: This would probably get a better response on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What is it you want us to explain?

Comment: k thanks for ur response. i ll check in math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be more clear about what you actually want and why (if that's relevant).

Your first equation is not homogeneous. To make it homogeneous you can write it in this form:

`x[n]+1 = (x[n-1]+1)+(x[n-2]+1)`

and substitute `u[n] = x[n] + 1` to get

`u[n] = u[n-1]+u[n-2]` with `u[0] = 1`, `u[1]=2`.

These numbers are known as [Fibonacci Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). There are several formulas and results regarding these numbers. For example

`u[n-2] = (phi^n - (-phi)^(-n)) / sqrt5` with `phi = (1 + sqrt 5) / 2 = 1.618...`

which gives a formula for `x[n]` in your original equation:

`(phi^(n+2) - (-phi)^(-n-2)) / sqrt5 - 1`

On the other hand, your other equation `y[n] = y[n-1] + n` can be reiterated as

`y[n] = y[n-1] + n = y[n-2] + (n-1) + n = ... = 1 + 2 + ... + n`

It is well known that this sum is `y[n] = n(n+1)/2`

I see no obvious relation between `x[n]` and `y[n]` as you provided.

Comment: now i edited the last line. Does it make sense now

Comment: If y[n] are Fibonacci numbers then x(n)=y(n+2)-1 is true. There is no relation with the definition 
'y(n)=y(n-1)+n where n>1 and y(0)=0 and y(1)=1' you provided.

Comment: could you provide the induction proof for x(n)=y(n+2)-1 taking y(n) as Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: I just showed above that u[n] are fibonacci numbers. that's because they satisfies the same recurrence relation and same initial conditions as fibonacci numbers y[n] (shifted by a couple indices). By induction, u[n] = y[n+2] for all n. But we defined x[n] = u[n]-1. So you get x[n] = y[n+1] - 1.